# Progress Bar not showing in fragment [ANDROID]

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

In my app i am using this library
https://github.com/DmitryMalkovich/circular-with-floating-action-button
to implement progress bar with floating action button. Its working on activity but when i included this layout in my fragment's layout progress bar doesn't show.
Here is my code for better explanation
Please guide me where i am going wrong
Any help will be appreciated.
**customlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
   >

<com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent_logo"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/bg_color"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           />

   </com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragmentlayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="bg_color"
    >
    <include
        layout="@layout/customlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/otherlayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am hiding and showing the parent layout of customlayout.xml on runtime when i get data from serivice, before service call i SHOW it with **View.VISIBLE** and after service call i HIDE it with **View.GONE**

**UPDATED**
**Java code**

**Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;

    //root view of layout
    View rootView;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Class";
    private String screen_title;
    private String URL = "";

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        MyFragmentfragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            screen_title = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
        //find views by ids
        getData();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void getData() {
        CustomClass.getInstance(context, rootView).show();
        //service call
       //on getting response from serivce (have implemented a listener here)
        CustomClass.getInstance(context, rootView).hide();    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
```

**CustomClass**

```
public class CustomClass {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    private static CustomClass custom;

    private CustomClass (Context context) {
        findViewsById(context);
    }

    private CustomClass (View view) {
        findViewsById(view);
    }

    public static CustomClass getInstance(Context context, View view) {
        custom = new CustomClass (view);
        custom.setPColor(context);
        return custom;
    }

    public static CustomClass getInstance(Context context) {
        custom = new CustomClass (context);
        custom.setPColor(context);
        return custom;
    }

    private void setPColor(Context context) {
        if (mProgressBar != null)
            mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bluecolor), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    private void findViewsById(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_progressbar);
            mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_floatingActionButton);
            parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_progress_fab_container);

        }
    }

    private void findViewsById(Context context) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        if (activity != null) {
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.custom_progressbar);
            mFab = (FloatingActionButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.custom_floatingActionButton);
            parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.rl_progress_fab_container);

        }
    }

    public void show() {
        if (custom.parentLayout != null)
            custom.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide() {
        if (custom.parentLayout != null)
            custom.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Also add service code where do you hide or visible progressbar.

Comment: Change the order of FAB and progress bar

Comment: put your java code here

Comment: @AldrinMathew tried it, not working

Comment: @User instead of container hide , try `include` id as hide and show.

Comment: @User Why `include` has height as `match_parent` ? I think it should be `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

make your customlayout at the bottom with the parent layout.
so your z index for that layout is at the top and it will be visible and gone that can be seen by you.

Comment: you mean i should include customlayout.xml at the end in fragmentlayout.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) with FAB .

Just put your FAB inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

As you can see library sample code suggests to use it too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dmitrymalkovich.android.progressfabsample.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_backup_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFab" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton>

<com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_backup_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFab" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.dmitrymalkovich.android.ProgressFloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: and where will be the progress bar then? can you please provide a simple sample code

Comment: @User Just replace RealativeLayout with CoordinatorLayout. Actually you have sample app inside this lin github. Check implementation [here](https://github.com/DmitryMalkovich/circular-with-floating-action-button/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_scrolling.xml)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
            //find views by ids
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getData();
                }
            });
            return rootView;
  }
```

or

```
private void getData() {
     getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CustomClass.getInstance(context, rootView).show();

        CustomClass.getInstance(context, rootView).hide(); 
                }
            });

 }
```